# I tried using the read file function but it does not work

Tags: python

I keep on trying to read a file on the computer:

```py
f = open("C:\\Users\\Yuzu\\Documents\\Python Data\file.txt", "w")

f.write("Hello")

f.close()

f = ("C:\\Users\\Yuzu\\Documents\\Python Data\file.txt", "rt")

print(f.read())
```

But it says that there is a attribute error and also says that tuple does not contain read

Comment: you are missing `open` in f = ("C:\\Users\\Yuzu\\Documents\\Python Data\file.txt", "rt")

Answer (score 0):

change

```
f = ("C:\Users\Yuzu\Documents\Python Data\file.txt", "rt")
```

to

```
f = open("C:\Users\Yuzu\Documents\Python Data\file.txt", "rt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot an `open` instruction. It should be

```py
f = open("C:\Users\Yuzu\Documents\Python Data\file.txt", "w")

f.write("Hello")

f.close()

f = open("C:\Users\Yuzu\Documents\Python Data\file.txt", "rt")

print(f.read())
```

otherwise you are just declaring `f` as the tuple containing the string of your local path, and the string `"rt"`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code by adding Open funcution

```
f = open("C:\Users\Yuzu\Documents\Python Data\file.txt", "rt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `close` if you use `with open`. The file is closed automatically after writing:

```py
with open("C:\Users\Yuzu\Documents\Python Data\file.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot and `open` while reading. Also, you need to escape `\` with another `\` at all places.

Try this:

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\Yuzu\\Documents\\Python Data\\file.txt", "w")

f.write("Hello")

f.close()

f = open("C:\\Users\\Yuzu\\Documents\\Python Data\\file.txt", "rt")

print(f.read())

f.close()
```